# Getting Permission Denied response from _request() call

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I recently started getting a 'Permission Denied' response from our vimeo album.  Everything was working correctly and nothing has changed on the application.  Also, I checked and it appears no permissions have changed on the album or included videos in terms of permissions.  However, we did change the servers we're hosting our main site on, which resulted in a change of IP addresses but the site URL did not change.

Is it possible that the IP change somehow messed up the request we make to vimeo?  I looked in the admin settings on vimeo and didn't see anywhere we needed to specify IP addresses.

Basically, we're doing the following:

```
$vimeo = new phpVimeo(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$vimeo->setToken(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);

// **** GET THE VID DATA FROM VIMEO **** // 
$result = $vimeo->call('vimeo.albums.getVideos', array('album_id' => xxxxxxxx,full_response => '1'));
$videos = $result->videos->video;
```

And, as I said, this was working great for a while. Any ideas on what may have happened?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP address should be irrelevant to the API.

My guess is that your account was part of the Adobe email breach (you should have received an email about this). Vimeo reset some tokens relating to the Adobe email breach to ensure account security.

If you were not part of the breach, you can contact Vimeo directly via https://vimeo.com/help/contact to learn more.

Comment: This appears to be the case - it looks like our access token and access token secret were changed.  I just needed to update that on our side and we're back in action.  Thanks!